# Increase infinite scrolling pagination offset in sql query when multiple users insert new comments

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ajax infinite scrolling loads comments from a PHP script. The PHP script increases a variable `$load++` for each comment. Then is used in the sql `OFFSET $load` and sends it back in a div to AJAX in the success function, the users scrolls again the value of the variable is send to PHP again it retrieves the next set of comments, this works, but:

If multiple users comment on that post the offset variable `$load` dose not increment and if a user scrolls now and triggers the AJAX script the new comments are not loaded instead the last comment is duplicated since the `offset` has not change.

Is there a better way to set that `offset` variable, or am I doing this wrong? What are the better ways for this kind of pagination? What method should i use so the scripts loads the next new comments if there are any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any code, I will give you only the idea of approach I used.

I assume you have some unique comment identifiers in your database, preferably an auto-incrementing ID. What this gives you is that every new comment will have a greater ID than the previous one. So when fetching comments from the database, you can store last comment's ID in your javascript code. Then when fetching more comments after reaching the end of a page, you send that ID to your PHP page. You can use that ID to select all the messages that are 'older' than the last message you selected, or in other words, have a smaller ID number.

A little demonstration:

```
id    |    comment    |  ....
1            test1
2            test2
3            test3
4            test4
5            test5
6            test6
```

Remember, comment with the ID 6 is the latest comment added.

Imagine you displayed comments 5, 4 and 3 on your page, and stored ID 3 in your javascript as your last comment. Now comment with the ID 6 is added to the database. You try to get new comments and send the ID you stored, ID 3. In your PHP script, you select the next five comments with the ID lower than 3. In this case, that will be 2 and 1

```
SELECT id, comment, .... FROM comments WHERE post = ... AND id < 3
```

Even though a new comment was added, that didn't make any difference because you had saved your last comment's ID and you know what comment comes next. As you can see, this code doesn't use `OFFSET`.

You can store comment's timestamp instead of the ID.

Since the ID is stored on client's side, users can tamper with the variable that stores the last comment's ID/timestamp but if that data is used properly in PHP, nothing can happen.

Of course, this may not be the best approach and maybe there are better examples. I used this and it served me very well.

Comment: This is the approach that i also found on a few websites and it seems to be the best for now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your current approach properly, however, I what did Nie on of my previous project and that worked, I maintained a is variable in my page called call_seq initialize with zero. Each time the pagination called the cause is increased and sent with the Ajax call.

On the php,10 comments are loaded on each call, so in sql queries, the offset is set using the value 10*call_seq.